# Copiar diretório para outro em site

Tags: php, javascript, node.js

Possuo um site em PHP e JavaScript. Defini um botão com a seguinte função (encontrei na internet, chamada `wrench.copyDirSyncRecursive`):

```
function atualizaIR(){
    dir1 = '201.7.201.173/Documentos/Teste1';
    dir2 = '201.7.201.173/Documentos/Teste2';
    wrench.copyDirSyncRecursive(dir1,dir2);
    alert('IRs atualizados!');
}
```

Sendo que a função (que está atrelada a um botão que criei na página) deveria copiar todo o conteúdo do diretório `Teste1` para o diretório `Teste2`.

Sei que há várias formas de fazer essa cópia de arquivos, mas ainda não consegui a mais eficiente que funcionasse pra esse site do meu cliente. Além disso, a pasta `dir1` pode estar em um disco rígido C da máquina com esse IP, enquanto a pasta `dir2` pode estar em um disco rígido D, na máquina desse mesmo IP.

Será que é muito difícil de fazer?

**edição**

Fiz da seguinte forma. No arquivo JS, tem essa função:

```
function atualizaIR(){
$.ajax({
      async: true, 
      cache:false, 
      url: '[:raiz]consultaRendimentos/atualizaIR',
      dataType: 'json',      
      type: 'POST',
      success: function(data) {
          alert('IRs atualizados!');
      }
});
}
```

E no arquivo Controller, fiz da seguinte forma (baseado no w3schols.com):

```
public function atualizaIR(){
    // connect and login to FTP server
    $ftp_server = "http://201.7.201.173/";
    $ftp_conn = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Could not connect to $ftp_server");
    $login = ftp_login($ftp_conn, $ftp_user, $ftp_password);

    $local_file = '../Documentos/Teste1/';
    $server_file = '../Documentos/Teste2/';

    // initiate download
    $d = ftp_nb_get($ftp_conn, $local_file, $server_file, FTP_ASCII);

    do{
        // do whatever you want
        // continue downloading
        $d = ftp_nb_continue($ftp_conn);
    }while ($d == FTP_MOREDATA);

    if ($d != FTP_FINISHED)
    {
        echo "Error downloading $server_file";
        exit(1);
    }

    // close connection
    ftp_close($ftp_conn);
}
```

Mas não funcionou. Dentro do meu servidor, não foi feita a cópia dos arquivos do Teste2 pro Teste1 ou vice-versa. Devo estar esquecendo muita coisa pra que essa cópia de arquivos aconteça.

Comment: Copiar diretórios com JS??? Edit: agora eu vi que isso é [Node.js](https://github.com/ryanmcgrath/wrench-js). Se vc tem conhecimento em Node, vá em frente, se não, sugiro [PHP mesmo](http://php.net/manual/en/book.ftp.php)

Comment: Acho que isso vai ajudar se for em nodejs https://www.npmjs.com/package/ncp Caso seja em javascript e php o melhor a fazer é com AJAX.

Comment: Chega a entrar dentro do método `atualizaIR` no PHP? Faça um debug colocando um ponto de paragem dentro do método, ou simplimente faça um `echo "Teste"; die();` e veja no Chrome, por exemplo, o resultado do POST Request utilizando a console .Da maneira como está na pergunta, vai apenas fazer um POST ao servidor porém não vai entrar dentro do método `atualizaIR`, a não ser que a classe tenha o mesmo nome, uma vez que no PHP5 ainda é possível ter o método construtor com o mesmo nome da classe.